# Unable to build a windows image in docker hub

Tags: docker

I am trying to autobuild an image(windows) in docker hub but its failing with below error

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxxxxxxxxxx' 
to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'18.03.1-ee-3', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': 
{u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2018- 
08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.37', u'MinAPIVersion': 
u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'b9a5c95', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': 
u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.10.2'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.37
Platform: {u'Name': u''}
Version: 18.03.1-ee-3
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: b9a5c95
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.10.2
Starting build of index.docker.io/cn1docker/powershellreminder:latest...
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
```

I have placed the docker file in my Github account and its trying to do autobuild while any new push happened.

Comment: Can you please share the repo link? how are you using autobuild from hub.docker.com?

Comment: @HernanGarcia My repo link :- https://github.com/git-chinmay/myDocker/tree/master/ReminderDockerbuild

Comment: @HernanGarcia I have successfully autobuild for a python script but while trying for powershell its failing.

Comment: yeah because python one is a Linux based docker image and this one is Windows, I don't see where are you building the image so I am completely out of context, can you please elaborate? are you triggering the auto-build from hub.docker.com? or from where? because I can't see any `.github...` file

Comment: I have linked the Github repository to my docker hub repository and configured the auto build.Whenever I will commit any changes to files in Github it will trigger an auto build in Docker hub. (cloud.docker.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly it seems as for now docker autobuild doesn't support Windows builds
https://forums.docker.com/t/automated-windows-builds/24192/5